# Ansible notify syntax issue - name ^ no action detected in task

Tags: syntax, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-handlers, netdata

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

**Ansible 2.1.2.0**

**Python 2.7.5**

**CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)**

**Playbook** file looks like:

```
[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible] $ cat netdata.yml 

---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
    - netdata

[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible] $
```

**Role's (netdata) main.yml looks like:**

```
[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible] $ cat roles/netdata/tasks/main.yml 

---
# ansible-playbook -i

#- name: Netdata details
#  debug: 
#    msg: "server = {{ netdata_server }}"
##
#- name: Check if netdata systemctl is running
#  command: "systemctl status netdata"
#  ignore_errors: yes
#  register: netdata_systemctl_status
#
#- name: Report status of Netdata Service
#  debug: 
#    msg: "{{ netdata_systemctl_status.stdout_lines }}"
#
- name: Start netdata systemctl if it is not running
  debug: 
    msg: "Restarting netdata systemctl now"
  notify: restart netdata systemctl

  #when: netdata_systemctl_status | failed

[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible] $
```

Handler's notifying the notifier and it's main file looks like:

```
[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible] $ cat roles/netdata/handlers/main.yml 

---
# PS.
# Order of listing notifiers in this file matters.
# Order of listing notifiers while calling/notifying a notifier in a task/action doesn't.

- name: restart netdata systemctl
  systemd: 
    name: netdata
    state: restarted

[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible] $
```

Then, why Ansible is giving me the following error?

```
[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible] $ ansible-playbook -i "`hostname`," --connection=local netdata.yml 
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/home/vagrant/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible/roles/netdata/handlers/main.yml': line 6, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: restart netdata systemctl
  ^ here


The error appears to have been in '/home/vagrant/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible/roles/netdata/handlers/main.yml': line 6, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: restart netdata systemctl
  ^ here

[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/netdata_ansible/ansible] $
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Ansible show "ERROR! no action detected in task" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159193/why-does-ansible-show-error-no-action-detected-in-task-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`systemd` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/systemd_module.html) was introduced in Ansible 2.2.

> **systemd - Manage services.**
>
> New in version 2.2.

You are using Ansible 2.1.2 hence Ansible reports no known action is defined in the task.

Comment: dang it.. thanks @techraf. I changed the subject line to reflect that `no known action`.

Comment: Is it possible for Ansible to always update itself first (to a given version) if a role/playbook is using something which is available in Ansible x.y+ version? or I guess, I need to clear that in the documentation myself for my playbook/role.

Comment: I guess not many people would appreciate automatic updates. Check this for other ideas [Require a minimum Ansible version in your Playbook](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2016/require-minimum-ansible-version-your-playbook)