# Why does Ansible show "ERROR! no action detected in task" error?

Tags: ansible

Ansible shows an error:

> ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

**What is wrong?**

---

The exact transcript is:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in 'playbook.yml': line 10, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: My task name
  ^ here
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

## Reason #1

**You are using an older version of Ansible which did not have the module you try to run.**

How to check it?

1. Open the list of modules [module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_all_modules.html) and find the documentation page for your module.
2. Read the header at the top of the page - it usually shows the Ansible version in which the module was introduced. For example:

   > New in version 2.2.
3. Ensure you are running the specified version of Ansible or later. Run:

   ```
   ansible-playbook --version
   ```

   And check the output. It should show something like:

   > ansible-playbook 2.4.1.0

---

## Reason #2

**You tried to write a role and put a playbook in `my_role/tasks/main.yml`.**

The `tasks/main.yml` file should contain only a list of tasks. If you specified:

```
---
- name: Configure servers
  hosts: my_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: My first task
      my_module:
        parameter1: value1
```

Ansible tries to find an action module named `hosts` and an action module named `tasks`. It doesn't, so it throws an error.

Solution: specify only a list of tasks in the `tasks/main.yml` file:

```
---
- name: My first task
  my_module:
    parameter1: value1
```

---

## Reason #3

**The action module name is misspelled.**

This is pretty obvious, but overlooked. If you use incorrect module name, for example `users` instead of `user`, Ansible will report "no action detected in task".

Ansible was designed as a highly extensible system. It does not have a limited set of modules which you can run and it cannot check "in advance" the spelling of each action module.

In fact you can write and then specify your own module named `qLQn1BHxzirz` and Ansible has to respect that. As it is an interpreted language, it "discovers" the error only when trying to execute the task.

---

## Reason #4

**You are trying to execute a module not distributed with Ansible.**

The action module name is correct, but it is not a standard module distributed with Ansible.

If you are using a module provided by a third party - a vendor of software/hardware or another module shared publicly, you must first download the module and place it in appropriate directory.

You can place it either in `modules` subdirectory of the playbook or in a common path.

Ansible looks `ANSIBLE_LIBRARY` or the `--module-path` command line argument.

To check what paths are valid, run:

```
ansible-playbook --version
```

and check the value of:

> configured module search path =

Ansible version 2.4 and later should provide a list of paths.

---

## Reason #5

**You really don't have any action inside the task.**

The task must have some action module defined. The following example is not valid:

```
- name: My task
  become: true
```

Comment: I wonder why having a task without action is a problem for ansible.  I might want to create a task that fails when variables have specific values.

Comment: Sophisticated answer, and the loud headings suggest completeness, but reason #6 is missing, see the next answer: in some installations you should not include the FQN but just the short module name

Answer (score 7):

I can't really improve upon @techraf answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159200/619760.
I wanted to add reason #6 my special case

## Reason #6

**Incorrectly using `roles:` to import/include roles as a subtask.**

This does not work, you can not include roles in this way as subtasks in a play.

```
---
- hosts: somehosts
  tasks:

  - name: include somerole
    roles:
      - somerole
```

### Use include_role

According to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#id6)

> you can now use roles inline with any other tasks using import_role or include_role:

```
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "before we run our role"
  - import_role:
      name: example
  - include_role:
      name: example
  - debug:
      msg: "after we ran our role"
```

### Put the roles at the right place inline with hosts

Include the roles at the top

```
---
- hosts: somehosts
  roles:
    - somerole
  tasks:   
    - name: some static task
      import_role:
        name: somerole
      hosts: some host
    - include_role:
        name: example
```

You need to understand the difference between [import/include static/dynamic](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#dynamic-vs-static)

Answer (score 7):

I got this error when I referenced the `debug` task as `ansible.builtin.debug`

Causes a syntax failure in CI (but worked locally):

```
- name: "Echo the jenkins job template"
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: template_xml
    verbosity: 1
```

Works locally and in CI:

```
- name: "Echo the jenkins job template"
  debug:
    var: template_xml
    verbosity: 1
```

I believe - but have not confirmed -  that the differences in local vs CI was ansible versions.

- Local : 2.10
- CI : 2.7

Answer (score 4):

**Explanation of the error :**

No tasks to execute means it can not do the action that was described in your playbook

**Root cause:**

- the installed version of Ansible doesn't support it

**How to check :**

- `ansible --version`

**Solution:**

- upgrade Ansible to a version which supports the feature you are trying to use

**How to upgrade Ansible:**

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#selecting-an-ansible-version-to-install

**Quick instruction for Ubuntu :**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt install ansible
```

P.S: followed this path and upgraded from version 2.0.2 to 2.9
After upgrade, same playbook worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem occurred with "systemd" module. Turned out that my `ansible --version` was **2.0.0.2** and module was first introduced in version **2.2**. Updating my ansible to latest version fixed the problem.

**playbook.yaml**

```
- name: "Enable and start docker service and ensure it's not masked"
  systemd:
    name: docker
    state: started
    enabled: yes
    masked: no
```

**Error**

```
ERROR! no action detected in task
etc..   
etc..
etc..

- name: "Enable and start docker service and ensure it's not masked"
  ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was fix:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the list by techraf and nelaaro, I discovered another way to get this error. Disclaimer: I'm forced to use a really old version of Ansible (2.3) -- this may not apply to more recent versions.

## Reason #7

Missing definitions for ANSIBLE_* environment variables

I put them in ~/.bash_profile

> export ANSIBLE_HOME=/home/ec2-user/--repo-name--/ansible
> export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/home/ec2-user/--repo-name--/ansible/inventory/ansible.cfg
> export ANSIBLE_LIBRARY=/home/ec2-user/--repo-name--/ansible/library

Answer (score -1):

another reason may be that you are using "ansible.builtin.XXXXX" instead of "XXXX" where it can be copy, yum, systemd etc as your ansible version does not support it