# I'm calling a module, Ansible still complains about "no action"

Tags: ansible

I'm getting an error with Ansible, "ERROR! No action detected in task." According to [Why does Ansible show "ERROR! no action detected in task" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159193/why-does-ansible-show-error-no-action-detected-in-task-error) , it looks like my error should be that I tried to write a role, and put a playbook in my `role/tasks/main.yml`. And the solution is to specify only a list of tasks in the `tasks/main.yml` file. Like this:

```
---
- name: My first task
  my_module:
    parameter1: value1
```

So my file looks like this:

```
---
- name: using a module
  ansible.builtin.command: echo hello there
```

So I am using a module, just like in the example shown elsewhere on StackOverflow, but still I get the error message. What am I missing?

This is for Ansible 2.9 on RHEL 7.7. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks. You should make this an answer so that I can mark it as the answer. I guess I was sleepy last evening! Thanks for the reply, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using ansible v2.9.

The (optional) full `<namespace>.<collection>.<module_name>` you are using in your task is only valid starting from ansible v2.10.

**Use the short name**: `ansible.builtin.command` => **`command`**.

You can also switch to the [ansible v2.9 version on the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/command_module.html) on the site to prevent this kind of problem when copy/pasting. See the dropdown on the top left

[image: ansible documentation site]

Answer (score -1):

From the information you provided here it doesn't appear that you're using an actual module, but instead you've placed a task list file in a module search path. Modules are implemented as programming language code that gets bundled and piped over the connection plugin to be executed in order to carry out task work on the managed host in the inventory.